# React components not rendering when routing to new page with react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to set up routing in my React app. I am not getting any error and the app is not breaking but when I navigate to a new page nothing is displayed. I am using react-router-dom v6 and 'Switch' has been replaced with 'Routes' and component has been replaced with element: https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/. It also appears you do not need the leading "/".

EDIT at bottom of page.

`http://localhost:3000/Player` and `http://localhost:3000/*` (or anything other than the * ) both render blank screens.

This is the landing page which works fine:

#### HomePage.tsx

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import React from 'react';
import { css } from '@emotion/react';
import logo from '../assets/cyberpunk.png';

export const HomePage = () => (
  <div
    css={css`
      margin: 10px auto 20px auto;
      padding: 30px 20px;
      max-width: 1000px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
    `}
  >
    <div>
      <img
        src={logo}
        alt="Logo"
        css={css`
          width: 700px;
          margin-left: 130px;
        `}
      />
      <h2>Players</h2>
      <button>Select a toon</button>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

This is the player page:

#### PlayerPage.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

export const PlayerPage = () => <h2>"One toon"</h2>;
```

The page not found page:

#### NotFoundPage.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

export const NotFoundPage = () => <h2>"Page Not Found"</h2>;
```

Finally,

### App.tsx

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import React from 'react';
import { css } from '@emotion/react';
import { Header } from './header';
import { HomePage } from './Views/HomePage';
import { fontFamily, fontSize, gray2 } from './Styles';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { PlayerPage } from './Views/PlayerPage';
import { PlayersPage } from './Views/PlayersPage';
import { PlayerCreatePage } from './Views/PlayerCreatePage';
import { NotFoundPage } from './Views/NotFoundPage';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div
        css={css`
          font-family: ${fontFamily};
          font-size: ${fontSize};
          color: ${gray2};
        `}
      >
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="Players" element={<PlayersPage />} />
          <Route path="Player" element={<PlayerPage />} />
          <Route path="Create" element={<PlayerCreatePage />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Why would the h2 elements in the NotFoundPage and PlayerPage not be being displayed? It acts like I'm navigating to an incorrect route every time.

I fixed it kind of. I remade one of the pages to look like this:

```
function PlayerCreatePage() {
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: 20 }}>
      <h2>About View</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adip.</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PlayerCreatePage;
```

And this one does show up. Why is that? What is wrong with the other views?

Comment: I think you are missing the backslash before all your path values. I'm also not sure which version of react-router-dom you are using. I was expecting a Switch component instead of Routes, and "component" Route prop instead of "element".

Comment: @Mary Looks like in react-router-dom v6 'Switch' has been replaced with 'Routes'.

Comment: @GrillOwner69420
 Are you able to resolve this issue? Is any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your error but was unable to. At first, I thought it might be an issue with you not writing return() inside the functions but then I realised you have exported without curly braces, so return isn't necessary. Anyway, the code runs fine, you should have tried to recreate in a new environment. Peace!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).